# Flask not displaying debug mode

Tags: flask

```
# python manage.py debug
 * Serving Flask app "server/__init__.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

Then raising an error in Firefox yields

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

This used to work at some point, but now it isn't.

FLASK_DEBUG = true or 1, does not work

FLASK_ENV = development, does not work

Comment: What does the Flask console show when that error happens?

Comment: the errors do show on the console, just no traceback on the webpage.